# How to get/ print a current value in a tkinter radiobutton

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, radio-button

I am trying to print a current value of a radiobutton in a oop structured application. I have seen a couple of solutions on how to write a working code (for example https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/tk_radiobutton.htm) but when I try to use it in my classes I am doing something wrong.

I have the following background code:

```
class OutFileGUI(tk.Tk): 

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):

        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs) 

        tk.Tk.wm_title(self, ".Out GUI") 

        container = tk.Frame(self)
        container.pack(side='top', fill='both', expand=True)
        container.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        container.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

        menubar = tk.Menu(container)
        filemenu = tk.Menu(menubar, tearoff=0)
        filemenu.add_command(label="Read file", command=self.open_file)
        filemenu.add_separator()
        filemenu.add_command(label="Exit", command=quit)
        menubar.add_cascade(label="File", menu=filemenu)

        tk.Tk.config(self, menu=menubar)

        self.frames = {}

        for F in (StartPage, MainPage, ConvBehaviour, GaussPoints):
            frame = F(parent=container, controller=self) =
            self.frames[F] = frame
            frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")

        self.show_frame(StartPage)

    def show_frame(self, page_name):

        frame = self.frames[page_name]
        frame.tkraise()

    def get_page(self, page_class):
        return self.frames[page_class]

    def open_file(self):
        name = askopenfilename(
                               filetypes=((".Out File", "*.out"), ("All Files", "*.*")),
                               title="Choose a file.")

        message = ("File location: " + str(name))
        print(message)
```

In the frame below I am trying to place a radiobutton and depending on the selected value by a user print the value.

```
class ConvBehaviour(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.controller = controller
        label = tk.Label(self, text="See behaviour", font=LARGE_FONT)
        label.pack(pady=10, padx=10)

        button1 = ttk.Button(self, text="Back to Home",
                             command=lambda: controller.show_frame(MainPage))
        button1.pack()

        button2 = ttk.Button(self, text="See points statistics",
                             command=lambda: controller.show_frame(GaussPoints))
        button2.pack()

        norms = [("norm 1", 1),
                 ("norm 2", 2),
                 ("norm 3", 3)]
                                                  #Here is the problem
        self.v1 = tk.IntVar()
        self.v1.set(1)

        for text, num in norms:
            radiobutton = tk.Radiobutton(self, text=text, value=num, variable=self.v1, command=self.show_choice)
            radiobutton.pack()


    def show_choice(self):
        print('int ' + str(self.v1.get()))
```

The problem I have is that the method show_choice(self) does not work in the current implementation. It prints the current value set in self.v1.set(1) instead of either of 1, 2, 3 depending on a user selection. Where does the problem lie?

Answer (score 0):

Try to build a minimal example as possible such that the problem of the variable not catching the user input still showing up while removing as much background noise as possible. See also https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

For example, the most minimal example only containing the radiobuttons I can build from your code is the following (and it is working as intended):

```
import tkinter as tk

def main():
    root = tk.Tk()

    norms = [("norm 1", 1),
             ("norm 2", 2),
             ("norm 3", 3)]

    v1 = tk.IntVar()
    v1.set(1)

    def show_choice():
        print('int ' + str(v1.get()))

    for text, num in norms:
        radiobutton = tk.Radiobutton(root, text=text, value=num, variable=v1, 
            command=show_choice)
        radiobutton.pack()

    root.mainloop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Try to build from there up - in small steps (maybe first try to add your own class inheriting from tk.Frame, etc.). This is essential: dont copy big chunks of code (with confusing classes and conventions) from someone else, but start from small working examples and work upwards.